# Exception in thread “main” java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: g != java.lang.String

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I am a bit new to java and was hoping if anyone could help me. I'm writing this code on  virtual machine Ubuntu using the text editor. The RAM errors is right here if you would like to reference the file. http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~crahn/CGS3767/RAMerrors. The error is located in the public static readingLine in the System.out.printf. If anyone could help me idenify the error, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class MemoryCalculator 
{
    private static Scanner convertingFiles;
    public static String convertFile = "RAMerrors.txt";

  public static void readFile(String nameOfFile) throws IOException
  {
      convertingFiles = new Scanner(new File(nameOfFile));
  }

  public static void readingLine(String nameOfFile) throws IOException
  {
      System.out.println();
      int recordingNum = 0;
        while(convertingFiles.hasNext())
        {
            recordingNum = recordingNum +1;
            String recordingLine = convertingFiles.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("( %d) %g ) \n", recordingNum, recordingLine );
            String conv = fromHexToBi(recordingLine);
            long decimal = fromBiToDec(conv);
            System.out.println(errorRamRangeWeb(decimal));
        }
  }

  public static String fromHexToBi(String input)
  {

      int fromHexToBi = 0;
      String record = "";
      char var;

      for(int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++)
      {
          var = input.charAt(x);

          if(var == '0')
          {
              record += "0000";
          }
          else if (var == '1')
          {
              record += "0001";
          }
          else if (var == '2')
          {
              record += "0010";
          }
          else if (var == '3')
          {
              record += "0011";
          }
          else if (var == '4')
          {
              record += "0100";
          }
          else if (var == '5')
          {
              record += "0101";
          }
          else if (var == '6')
          {
              record += "0110";
          }
          else if (var == '7')
          {
              record += "0111";
          }
          else if (var == '8')
          {
              record += "1000";
          }
          else if (var == '9')
          {
              record += "1001";
          }
          else if (var == 'A')
          {
              record += "1010";
          }
          else if (var == 'B')
          {
              record += "1011";
          }
          else if (var == 'C')
          {
              record += "1100";
          }
          else if (var == 'D')
          {
              record += "1101";
          }
          else if (var == 'E')
          {
              record += "1110";
          }
          else if (var == 'F')
          {
              record += "1111";
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.print("Sorry, the error is .out of range");
          }
      }
      System.out.println(record);
      return record;
  }

  public static long fromBiToDec(String bi)
  {
      long decimal = 0;

      for(int y = 0; y < bi.length(); y++)
      {
          if(bi.charAt(y) == '1')
          {
              decimal = (long) (decimal + Math.pow(2, bi.length() - 1 - y));
          }
      }
      System.out.println(decimal);
      return (long) decimal;
  }

  public static String errorRamRangeWeb(long decimal)
  {
      String chipRangeFall = "";

      long errorRamRange0 = 0;

      long errorRamRange1 = 8589934584L;

      long errorRamRange2 = 8589934585L;

      long errorRamRange3 = 1717986184L;

      long errorRamRange4 = 17179869185L;

      long errorRamRange5 = 25769803768L;

      long errorRamRange6 = 25769803769L;

      long errorRamRange7 = 34359738368L;

      long result = decimal;

      if((result >= errorRamRange0) && (result <= errorRamRange1))
      {
          chipRangeFall = "1";
      }
      else if ((result >= errorRamRange2) && (result <= errorRamRange5))
      {
          chipRangeFall = "2";
      }
      else if ((result >= errorRamRange4) && (result <= errorRamRange3))
      {
          chipRangeFall = "3";
      }
      else if ((result >= errorRamRange6) && (result <= errorRamRange7))
      {
          chipRangeFall = "4";
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("ram chip does not exist");
      }
      return chipRangeFall;

  }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        readFile(convertFile);
        readingLine(convertFile);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem or question? And where is it occurring? Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 3):

You want a `%s` conversion for your `String` argument `recordingLine`, not `%g`

Answer (score 1):

recordingLine is expected to be float but found to be string.